# Git repository structure for two iOS apps where one app derives heavily from the other

Tags: ios, git, version-control, branching-and-merging

The scenario is as follows.  I am working at a company that started out with one iOS application.  Now, the company is interested in creating a second iOS application, that shares much of the same code base.  The original application was not written with the intention of being reusable, as it was not known at the time that a second similar application would be created.  In future, there may be even more similar applications that build on the existing code base.

We are trying to determine the "best" option with respect to how we maintain the source code going forward.  So some of the options we're contemplating include single repository with shared library, one repository for shared library and one repository that contains all of the iOS applications, one repository for shared library and one repository per iOS application, etc etc.  There's also the question of whether to use git submodules or not if using multiple repositories etcetera.

Currently, the two applications + library are all in one git repository.  One of the advantages of this is that a developer can checkout a commit of the single repository and expect the product to build, without having to worry about updating multiple repositories.  Basically, the developer doesn't have to be concerned with multiple repositories needing to move in lockstep with one another or requiring some specific combination of repositories commits for a build to work.  The developer also doesn't have to worry about cases where another developer may have remembered to commit one repository, but not the other.

Here are some more things I've considered:

### Submodules

I've used submodules before, but am no expert.  My understanding is that the "super" repository containing a submodule also stores a reference to a specific commit of the submodule.  This partly deals with ensuring that multiple repositories (i.e. application + library) would move in lockstep, though I'm guessing there are still issues with needing to manually pull changes from the sub module.  Also, issues with a submodule commit not being available to pull if a developer happens to forget to push its changes and it is referred to by the super repository.

One nice aspect of submodules is that it creates a stronger semantic separation between the library and the applications which happen to use the library.  Whether this is useful in practice, I'm not sure.

### Single repository

As previously stated, this is what we're currently doing.  Two applications + shared library code all in one repository.  The greatest concern has been around the relatively non-existent ability to isolate changes between project one and two and the library.  E.g. someone makes changes to both some library code and some application code in a single commit.  Then, another developer just wants the changes in the library code.

One nice aspect of single repository is that everything moves in lockstep - nobody has to worry about keeping multiple repository versions matched.  If using XCode workspaces, refactorings are even possible across the two applications.

### Branching

Another option is to use some kind of branching model, either in a single or multiple repositories, to manage the code.

Ultimately, we're just trying to figure out a good model going forward for managing two or more iOS applications plus shared library code.  Whether this be achieved via multiple repositories, submodules, branching models, or something else.  Any general suggestions on the pros and cons of the various options?

Answer (score 0):

Use submodules.  You don't need to be an expert because they are really easy to use.  Especially when combined with a GUI like SourceTree.  I had the exact same scenario as you and that is what I did.  SourceTree will even warn you if you are trying to commit a repo that has uncommited changes in a submodule.

A single repository is ludicrous.  That would mean that every time someone new wanted to download a project, they would have to download them all.

Branching is going to turn out to be too complicated with making bug fixes that apply to all relevant branches.

The structure I have for my current project is:

Project repo (For the project I am personally working on)
-Project base repo (For shared code between team members)
--Utilities repo (For code that is reusable in any project)

Answer (score 0):

[Cocoapods](http://cocoapods.org/), they make managing related code between applications simple.

We had a similar base for a suite of apps and initially it was a huge pain to manage but once you get custom cocoapods running you will never look back. You should check out [this](http://i.ndigo.com.br/2012/04/using-cocoapods-for-in-house-components/) for a starting guide on managing your own cocoapods.

It's free, it's powerful and you will wonder why you never used them sooner.